# Which binding type does PDO use by default?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

According to the documentation you can do a bind in 3 main ways: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

```
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);

$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));

$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
```

The 1st method you can specify the Param_(Str/int) to match up with your table and make sure the correct user info was given. Do the other two auto-find what data type the table is? How do the other two choose their data types? Seems like the 1st one is more secure.

Comment: i believe for the other two they are treated as strings.

Comment: The documentation for `execute` that you linked to says, under Parameters: "*All values are treated as **`PDO::PARAM_STR`**.*"

Comment: @DCoder you have literally delivered face-palm on op :D

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for execute that you linked to says, under Parameters: "All values are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`